# 404 for javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, path

I am having a weird issue where my jquery.js script is found but my personal javascript file is not even though it's in the same directory (same level too in the directory) as the jquery.js script.

My lines of code are:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="injectLastCell.js"></script>
```

The first script loads, but the second spits out a "code 404, message File not found".

The injectLastCell.js is composed of the following of the code (I have tested it on jsfiddle so I know it works):

```
function createForm(i, value) {
    return $('<input/>').attr({ type: 'text', id: i, name: i, value: value});
}


$("table tr td:last-child").each(function(i, e) {
    createForm(i, "v"+i).appendTo($(e));
});
```

Anyone have an idea of what is going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You sure the filename is spelt correctly, including upper / lower case letters?

Comment: Have you checked the file permissions of injectLastCell.js ?

Answer (score 0):

So I made a rookie mistake.  I was using notepad to save my file and didn't see that it was appending .txt to the end of the file name.  I switched to using notepad++ which allows saving for .js and everything is golden.

Thanks everyone for the suggestions.